# StackOverflow и Pastebin

Tags: обсуждение

Я задал вопрос, и вставил туда следующую команду:

```
ping 10.658941
```

И буквально сразу(!) это появилось на Pastebin ([пруфлинк](https://www.google.com/search?q=ping%2010.658941&ie=utf-8&oe=utf-8&client=firefox-b)).

Вопрос: Pastebin индексирует SO, и любой код (команда) попадает туда молниеносно?

Comment: Интересное наблюдение.

Comment: *"По запросу ping 10.658941 ничего не найдено"*. Странный у вас какой-то пруфлинк...

Comment: @PavelMayorov, да, вроде, работает: https://i.stack.imgur.com/jbDGT.png

Comment: Я бы для начала проверил, не установлено ли в браузере никакого расширения, работающего с pastebin?

Comment: Где-то я уже читал подобное. Кажется, [тут](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/272384/3240681).

Comment: @АндрейNOP а у меня только ruSO [находит](https://i.stack.imgur.com/P9v3U.png).

Comment: @älёxölüt, это странно, потому что у меня уже 3 результата (добавилась еще и эта страница)

Comment: @insolor, нет, не установлено.

Comment: У меня тоже только ruSO.

Comment: @АндрейNOP уверены, что у вас  мета добавилась, а не что-то другое? http://i.imgur.com/FfN4nLp.png <- у меня, например результатов с меты нет.

Comment: @Dillingerèmorto, упс, уже пропала, появилось что-то другое: https://i.stack.imgur.com/e1v1U.png

Comment: @АндрейNOP пути гугла неисповедимы!

Comment: @älёxölüt есть у вас какие-нибудь предположения относительно того, почему в гугле изначально я нашёл это на пастебине, а уже потом на SO?

Comment: Я [чуть выше](https://ru.meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/8165/stackoverflow-%d0%b8-pastebin#comment33789_8165) писал об этом :)

Comment: Тогда предлагаю закрыть вопрос, так как пути гугла неисповедимы)

Comment: Модеры, закройте пожалуйста этот вопрос с пометкой ``"Закрыт по причине того, что пути гугла неисповедимы"``.

Comment: Зачем закрывать? Просто удалите "вопрос 2". А первый вопрос интересен. Очевидно, что-то не может автоматически попасть на pastbin только из-за "неисповедимых путей".

Comment: А не может ли это быть происками одного из сайтов сдирающих весь контент с ruSO, и использующем pastebin как хранилище?

Answer (score 2):

[Вопрос](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/q/897550/178988) задан:

> 2018-10-24 20:11:28Z

[Pastebin](https://pastebin.com/RbgPh3nb) создан:

> Wednesday 24th of October 2018 03:14:01 PM CDT

[Конвертер](https://www.worldtimebuddy.com) говорит, что это эквивалентно

> 2018-10-24 20:14:01Z

**Получается, pastebin был создан через 2 минуты 33 секунды после вопроса на ruSO.**

Comment: Подождите, фишка в том, что я задал вопрос,и чето скопировал команду и вставил в гугл, буквально через (2) минуты, и обнаружил, что эта команда уже на пастебине, и больше ничего нет по запросу, кроме пастебина. Чуть позже, в гугле появилась инфа с руСО, и я чет попутал берега.

Comment: @Dillingerèmorto, сорри, я неправильно время перевёл, действительно, pastbin появился через 2 мин 33 сек после вопроса - довольно быстро.

Comment: довольно странно, почему первым делом код/команда появилась на пастебине, в выдаче гугла... Вам не кажется это немножко неправильно?

Answer (score 2):

Как Stack Exchange, так и Pastebin имеют собственный API, который можно использовать для автоматизации переноса данных с одного сайта на другой.

В данном случае выглядит как будто кто-то создал бота, который отслеживает появление примеров кода на SO по метке [сеть](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/%d1%81%d0%b5%d1%82%d1%8c) и переносит их на Pastebin. Вот еще один пример:

[как получить файл из network, используя java+selenium+webdriver](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/875276/%D0%BA%D0%B0%D0%BA-%D0%BF%D0%BE%D0%BB%D1%83%D1%87%D0%B8%D1%82%D1%8C-%D1%84%D0%B0%D0%B9%D0%BB-%D0%B8%D0%B7-network-%D0%B8%D1%81%D0%BF%D0%BE%D0%BB%D1%8C%D0%B7%D1%83%D1%8F-javaseleniumwebdriver)

https://pastebin.com/xQTzYFXx

Comment: А мне теперь интересно, это работает только для метки [tag:сеть], или и для других?

Comment: @Dillingerèmorto Возможно, и по другим. Мне пока что удалось раскопать три таких вопроса, между которыми единственное что было общим - наличие метки "сеть"